# Hive on window 10 using cygwin: Path error

Tags: hadoop, hive, cygwin

I got this error when install hive on window 10 using [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin).

I had added this code

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink /J  D:\cygdrive\d\ d:\

But the path like below. I think Cygwin doesn't understand  **cygdrive\d\hadoop\hive3.1.2....**

It must be **cygdrive/d/hadoop/hive3.1.2/....**

Error

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: File /cygdrive/d/hadoop/hive3.1.2\scripts\metastore\upgrade\mssql\upgrade.order.mssqlnot found
Underlying cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException : \cygdrive\d\hadoop\hive3.1.2\scripts\metastore\upgrade\mssql\upgrade.order.mssql (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

How can I fix this?

Update: Solved.
I was fixed by using Wsl instead of Cygwin. In Wsl, install openJdk8 of Java, set Java_home to /user/lib/jvm/openJdk8... then rerun hive command again. Done.
It seems Cygwin calls java of windows, it should be using Linux version.

Comment: I was fixed by using Wsl instead of Cygwin. In Wsl, install openJdk8 of Java, set Java_home to /user/lib/jvm/openJdk8.. then rerun hive command again. Done.

Comment: If you solved your question, don't put that in the question, add an answer and accept it instead.